# Zoology - Help identify the kind of spider

Tags: zoology, species-identification

Yesterday, I bought a banana tree (**Musa Basjoo**) from a local supermarket.
Today, I noticed a hive of small spiders on the tree.
I do not know where they came from, so I am curious to identify these small creatures.
I am living in Flossenbürg, Bavaria, Germany.

**Can someone help me identify the kind of spiders that are depicted on the photos?**

A picture of the tree, it is still in front of my house door, planted in a pot:
[image: a picture of the tree, it is still in front of my house door, planted in a pot.]

A near shot of the spiders that are "dwelling" on the tree:
[image: a near zoom shot of the spiders that are "dwelling" on the tree]

Answer (score 2):

Not too sure but it seems like the european garden spider- [*Araenus diadematus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araneus_diadematus)

[image]

[ [Image source](http://www.gettyimages.in/detail/photo/european-garden-or-cross-spider-spiderlings-high-res-stock-photography/106455259) ]